# Нужно чтобы try except в цикле переносил нас из функции на ввод переменных a b c

Tags: python, функции, try

Нужно чтобы try except в цикле переносил нас на ввод переменных, не знаю как сделать это, помогите..

```
import math
def fun(a, b, c):
    while True:
        if a == 0:
            print("a не может быть равно нулю")
            continue
        try:
            D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
        except OverflowError:
            print("Это перебор с цифрами")
            continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Это не целое или рациональное число")
            continue
        print("Дискриминант D = %.2f" % D)
        if math.isinf(D) or math.isnan(D):
            print("Габелла, бесконечность - предел(слишком большое число)")
            continue
        elif D > 0:
            x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
            x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
            print("x1 = %.2f \nx2 = %.2f" % (x1, x2))
        elif D == 0:
            x = -b / (2 * a)
            print("x = %.2f" % x)
        else:
            print("Корней нет")
        break

print("Введите коэффициенты для уравнения - целые или рациональные числа")
print("ax^1+bx+c=0")
a = float(input("a="))
b = float(input("b="))
c = float(input("c="))
fun(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Нужно не чтобы "try exept в цикле переносил нас на ввод переменных", а ввод переменных перенести в цикл.

Comment: нужно чтобы переменные он брал извне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как куда переносить непонятно я написал код, далее запустите функцию где вам надо:

```
import math

def input():
    print("Введите коэффициенты для уравнения - целые или рациональные числа")
    print("ax^1+bx+c=0")
    a = float(input("a="))
    b = float(input("b="))
    c = float(input("c="))
    fun(a, b, c)

def fun(a, b, c):
    while True:
        if a == 0:
            print("a не может быть равно нулю")
            continue
        try:
            D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
        except OverflowError:
            print("Это перебор с цифрами")
            continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Это не целое или рациональное число")
            continue
        print("Дискриминант D = %.2f" % D)
        if math.isinf(D) or math.isnan(D):
            print("Габелла, бесконечность - предел(слишком большое число)")
            continue
        elif D > 0:
            x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
            x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
            print("x1 = %.2f \nx2 = %.2f" % (x1, x2))
        elif D == 0:
            x = -b / (2 * a)
            print("x = %.2f" % x)
        else:
            print("Корней нет")
        break
```

Comment: переносить нужно на ввод переменных, то есть в начало, ошибка отработала и нужно заново ввести переменные a, b, c. Что куда вставить я не понял), объясните пж. Тип функции будут друг на друга ссылаться? в exepte поставить вызов функции input?

Comment: разобрался, спасибо)

Comment: Не нужно называть свою функцию именем встроенной функции. Вы не видите, что у вас функция input внутри использует функцию input? Она даже не будет работать, потому что выдаст ошибку

Answer (score -2):

так получилось в итоге, даже цикл не понадобился)

```
import math
def fun(a, b, c):

    if a == 0:
        print("a не может быть равно нулю")
        inp()
    try:
        D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
    except OverflowError:
        print("Это перебор с цифрами")
        inp()
    except ValueError:
        print("Это не целое или рациональное число")
        inp()
    print("Дискриминант D = %.2f" % D)
    if math.isinf(D) or math.isnan(D):
        print("Габелла, бесконечность - предел(слишком большое число)")
        inp()
    elif D > 0:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        print("x1 = %.2f \nx2 = %.2f" % (x1, x2))
    elif D == 0:
        x = -b / (2 * a)
        print("x = %.2f" % x)
    else:
        print("Корней нет")


def inp():
    print("Введите коэффициенты для уравнения - целые или рациональные числа")
    print("ax^1+bx+c=0")
    a = float(input("a="))
    b = float(input("b="))
    c = float(input("c="))
    fun(a, b, c)

inp()
```

Comment: в вашем коде рекурсия не уместна.

Comment: а как без рекурсии сделать? Всё работает, прям как надо. Очень интересно было бы узнать, как сделали бы вы)

Comment: "как сделали бы вы". Как и все, начинающие писать код на питоне без рекурсий. Через цикл в основном коде.

Comment: но мне нужно чтобы он из функции переходил на ввод переменных при ошибке, у меня не получается сделать это через цикл, еще слаб..

Comment: Да у меня тоже много чего не получается, но потихонку двигаюсь, не семимильными шагами как хотелось бы. Stackoverflow дает не плохую практику на писанию кода, это одна из причин почему я здесь.